# convert hexadecimal character string to integer

Tags: java

I'm beginner in Java. I'm reading data from the serial port and I have stored the data in a string array. Data has a length of 24 bytes.

Data I'm getting as output: 12120814330006050.0

Data also contains hexadecimal characters in the string. I want to read the first character of the string. I have done:

```
String str=dispArray[i].substring(1,2);
int i= Integer.parseInt(str,16);
System.out.println("Decimal:="+ i);
```

But I'm getting  NumberFormatException.

How can I read hexadecimal characters?

Comment: The special characters in this question are breaking the RSS feed for me :-(

Comment: Are you rohit or gopal? This data was first examined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336289/vc-60-serial-communicaton, so you're either faking user IDs for the hell of it or this is identical hardware. Closing as dupe.

Answer (score 3):

single characters you can get from a string with

```
str.getChar(0);
```

When you know that the string contains hex values in every character you dont have to convert every single character. You can put the complete string in and get the dec value of the hex string back. Otherwise you only calculate 1 hex value and has to multiplicate with the index number of the character position.

To parse it to an hex value you can call

```
Integer.parseInt(str,16);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your data stream actually contains a mixture of binary and text data. It's very important (IMO) that you *don't* try to store the whole thing as a string. Keep it as binary data, and convert appropriate chunks into text when you need to.

This may mean changing how you're reading from the serial port in the first place - use APIs which deal in bytes and byte arrays instead of chars and strings.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are unicode - so the bytes have already been decoded using some encoding (probably UTF-8?).

So:

1. Check the contents of the string.
2. Check the contents of the substring.